# The SDK Manager changed

Tags: android, eclipse

I checked "Help > Check for Updates" And I got the picture:[image]

It gave me two errors:

- No repository found at file:/C:/Users/riq/.
- No repository found at file:/F:/Learn%20eclipse/SDK/SDK/.

I changed the second one (No repository found at file:/F:/Learn%20eclipse/SDK/SDK/.) so I did Window > Preferences > Android like this picture:
[image]

in order to change it to (F:\SDK\sdk) but every showed the same as in the first picture and I didnt know what to add in the first error!
The eclipse has no Applications in the "Package Explorer" the "Project > Properties" is not highlighted!

How can I change them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in `Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites`.

Remove or uncheck any sites that refer to local directories that don't exist.

Comment: I removed the two errors, thank you very much greg-449, thank you Ramakishna Balla :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check where you've installed your Android (ADT bundle). Inside that folder you should see the structure like this...

`**C:\Android**\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk`. In Eclipse --> Windows --> Preferences, SDK Location should be directed to the path mentioned like this. In my case it is stored in C:\Android...replace it with your actual path. and Click Apply

From there on, you should see no issues when doing any updates.

On a site note, Try to restart the Eclipse and also restart the system if required. The preferences should directly point to your SDK path as mentioned above only then it can update without issues.

Comment: I downloaded adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321 again, I connected eclipse through "Window > Preferences > Android" to it and there was no problem, but in the "Help > Check for Updates" gave me the same exact error as in the first picture!

Comment: Are you able to work on your projects & run them without any issues ? If yes, ignore those errors.

Comment: I ran a new "Hello World" application while "Window > Preferences > Android" like second picture and its working fine, the "Help > Check for Updates" has the same error :)